# ARIMA/Holt Winters for multiple Time Series

Tags: python, time-series, arima, holtwinters

Is there a way of running an **ARIMA/Holt-Winters model** in python that deals with multiple items (time series) at once?

I can run a single ARIMA/Holt-Winters model using the StatsModels package in Python, but not for multiple Time Series.

To clarify what I mean by multiple Time Series, see my dataset.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**ARIMA** is one of the mostly used Models for time series forecasting but, It is suitable only for univariate time series analysis. In your dataset, there are four variables

- X1
- X2
- X3
- X4

So it is a multivariate time series.

For Handling, this kind of time series forecasting [**VECTOR AUTO REGRESSION**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_autoregression) is a good Choice. it is capable of handling any number of variable. Even though the computation is higher you will get a decent accuracy on the prediction.

you can easily import it from  [Stats_Model](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/vector_ar.html) by the following import statement:

```
from statsmodels.tsa.vector_ar.var_model import VAR
```

**VAR METHOD :**

```
model = VAR(array_of_data)
```

- where *arry_of_data* should be a list (each observation as a row)

**Input Format of Data:**

```
[[5737,5100,2899,7431.26],

[5779,5500,5600,5237.5],

[5782,3520,3620,6534.39]]
```

Before implementing it, carefully read all parameters for better result.

for more understanding read [this](https://machinelearningmastery.com/time-series-forecasting-methods-in-python-cheat-sheet/)

Comment: Note that VAR models are best suited for finding (inter-)dependencies between the different series over time. If there isn't a reason to think that any series impacts any others over time, VAR might be over-engineering.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
from statsmodels.tsa.vector_ar.var_model import VAR
import numpy as np
model = VAR(endog=np.asarray(train))
model_fit = model.fit()
prediction = model_fit.forecast(model_fit.y, steps=len(valid))
```